# AWS MediaLive - Schedule Input Switch not behaving as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, schedule, channel, aws-media-live

I wonder if anyone can please help.

I have a MediaLive channel with two file inputs: a 2-minute Countdown video and a 40-minute Main video.  Upon start, I want the channel to play the Countdown video first, followed by the Main video.  My schedule is as follows (set up from scratch with each test):

```
- 1. Start type: Immediate; Action: Input Switch; Input attachment: "Countdown" input
- 2. Start type: Follow "Countdown" input switch; Follow point: END; Action: Input Switch; File: "Main video"
```

My problem is that the channel goes directly to the Main video and does not play the Countdown.

I am viewing the output the moment it becomes available - well within 2 minutes of the channel starting - and I see the opening frames of the Main video each time [I did try swapping schedule around, so it should start with Main and follow with Countdown - again, it started with Main].  Both videos are identical format (mp4/1080/8Mbps/25fps).  For the record, the Countdown input is the first input attachment listed is channel settings.  Output is to MediaStore/CloudFront (new URL with each channel start, so not cached).

Any ideas where I might be going wrong here?  How I can make it play Countdown first?  Very much appreciate anyone's expert assistance!

Many thanks.

Comment: So as an experiment, I tried using a Fixed input switch schedule for the Countdown video (instead of Immediate), with a Follow switch to the Main video.  But now when I start the channel, the Countdown video plays *immediately* - not in the future!  And Main video does not play at all!  I have tried this with several times with different Fixed future times - including tomorrow afternoon.  Always with the same result: Countdown plays immediately, Main video does not Follow. Where am I going wrong with MediaLive channel Schedule actions!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question on stackoverflow, I pulled the logs for your channel and reviewed them and I am seeing we are failing to probe the main video and the HTTP transfer is failing, can you verify that the video is in the S3 bucket and that it's not corrupt?

Zach

Comment: Thank you for this response Zach!  Both videos are in S3 and both play fine locally. 

MediaLive does play the Main video perfectly on Immediate switch: it just skips the Countdown.  And on Fixed switch, it plays the Countdown *immediately* and ignores the Main video.  But I will test again with new videos & report back.

Is it possible that an undetected corruption in one of the videos could produce this behaviour?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Zach!  I did try a different Main MP4 file and this has fixed the Immediate Switch problem below! The channel now starts with Countdown and Follows with the Main video, as planned. It does seems strange that MediaLive fails the play the good file - and instead goes direct to the file it doesn't like! But I'm happy it's working as planned, so thank you for that.

The second issue remains: I've set the Fixed Input Switch to 2am June 16 (2 days in the future). But once started, the channel plays Countdown video immediately. And the Main video does not Follow the Countdown video.  Thanks!

Comment: Zach responded to me directly with the answers: 

"When a channel starts, it always starts with the first input. You could set a black slate as first input, then schedule a Countdown and follow with a Main video.  Or start with an immediate Pause action, schedule an Unpause at the time you want the Countdown to start - and create another scheduled Fixed action to start Main video at a specified time, or two minutes after the unpause which would be the time the Countdown should end."

Thank you Zach - question answered!!